# Excel displays ### even after autofit when printing to PDF

Tags: excel, pdf, printing, wysiwyg

I'm struggling with the view when exporting to Excel. All my cells are autofitted, but several of the cells display ### when exported to PDF.

Is there a way of adding an extra few percent when autofitting column widths in Excel, thereby leaving enough room for proper wysiwyg when printing to pdf?

Comment: I usually reduce the font size by one point, just before exporting to pdf. That seems to work, in most cases.